# Is $T^{\ast\ast}\subseteq T^\ast$ obvious for a symmetric operator $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb C$-Hilbert space and $T$ be a densely-defined symmetric linear operator on $H$.

> Can we show that $T^{\ast\ast}\subseteq T^\ast$ without using the fact that $T$ is closable and $\overline T$ is symmetric as well?

I know how we can easily prove the claim using the mentioned fact, since $$T^{\ast\ast}=\overline T\subseteq\overline T^\ast=T^\ast\tag1.$$ However, I've found the claim in several books at stages where the authors haven't defined the notion of the *closure* yet and since all of them mention the claim without any further remark I've got the strange feeling that the desired relation is way more obvious from the symmetry than I realize up to now.

Comment: Isn't "$T \subset T^{\ast}$" (where $T^{\ast}$ may be a relation, not necessarily a map) the definition of symmetric operators? And $A \subset B \implies B^{\ast} \subset A^{\ast}$ is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is symmetric you can check explicitly that $D(T)\subseteq D(T^*)$ and $T^*\lvert_{D(T)}=T$.

You can then prove $T^{**}\subseteq T^*$ from the definition:

Let $x\in D(T^{**})$, then there is a $C$ so that $|(x,T^{*}y)| ≤ C\,\|y\|$ for all $y\in D(T^*)$. In particular it holds for all $y\in D(T)$, where $T^*$ and $T$ agree, so the inequality becomes:
$$|(x,Ty)|≤ C\|y\| \  \ \forall y\in D(T)$$ 
giving that $x\in D(T^{*})$. Now $T^{**}x$ is determined by the extension of functional $y\mapsto (T^{**}x,y) = (x,Ty)$. But that is the same functional determining $T^*x$ (one initial domain is bigger than the other, but both are dense so the extensions to all of $H$ agree), hence you also have $T^{**}x=T^*x$ whenever $x\in D(T^{**})$.